# `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}` without each line being numbered?

Tags: latex

I want to use `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}` but do not want each line to be enumerated. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Addition}
\date{January 2022}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{thm}
Addition.
\begin{proof}
\begin{align}
    a + b &= b + a\\ 
\end{align}
\end{proof}
\end{thm}
    
\end{document}
```

This would create something like

```
Theorem 3. Addition example
Proof.
a + b = b + a        (1.1)
```

However, I do not want the `(1.1)` part, how do I remove it? Have tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30033/theorem-without-numbering) but the numbering is still added. Anyone know how to remove it?

Comment: Did you test your code? It does not compile because the necessary packages are missing.

Comment: Sorry I just took out the parts that I thought were necessary from a thesis thousands of lines long, may have missed an import. Sry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `align*` to suppress the numbering:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm,mathtools}
\title{Addition}
\date{January 2022}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{thm}
Addition.
\begin{proof}
\begin{align*}
    a + b &= b + a\\ 
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{thm}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh it was the `align` part that was the problem, thank you!